# Swift UITableView calls didSelectRowAt only if I press a few seconds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with customs UITableViewCell, but I'm having a strange issue, if I want the didSelectRowAt func to be called I need to press the cell (and stay pressed) for 2 seconds.

I tried with the didHighlightRowAt func, that takes less time (1 second) but I still need to press and wait for a second, if I do not, nothing happens.

my cellForRowAt func is the following one (I don't know if that can be related ?) :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = StationSearchCellView(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell", station: self.tableSearchesData[indexPath.section])

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
}
```

My custom cell is :

```
class StationSearchCellView : UITableViewCell {
    var stationName : String? init (
        style : UITableViewCellStyle,
        reuseIdentifier : String?,
        station : String
    )
    {
        super.init (style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.stationName = station let frameHeight = FDUtils.shared.heightRelativeToLayout (heightInPixels: 60)
        let iconSize = FDUtils.shared.widthRelativeToLayout (widthInPixels: 16)
        let marginWidth = FDUtils.shared.widthRelativeToLayout (widthInPixels: 20)
        // separator
        let separator = UIView (
            frame : CGRect (x: 0, y: 0-0.5, width: self.frame.width, height: 1)
        )
        separator.backgroundColor = FDColors.gray707070.withAlphaComponent (0.50)
        // Label Station
        let labelStation = UILabel (
            frame : CGRect (
                x : 0,
                y : 0,
                width : FDUtils.shared.elementsWidth - iconSize - marginWidth,
                height : frameHeight
            )
        )
        labelStation.text = station labelStation.setBlack_Left_Regular16 ()
        // Image fleche
        let searchIcon = UIImageView (
            frame : CGRect (
                x : labelStation.frame.width,
                y : labelStation.frame.height / 2 - iconSize / 2,
                width : iconSize,
                height : iconSize
            )
        )
        searchIcon.image = UIImage (named: "blue_select_icon")
        self.addSubview (separator)
        self.addSubview (labelStation)
        self.addSubview (searchIcon)
    }
    required init? (coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError ("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: My bet would be that you have a `UITapGestureRecognisor` on the view which needs to fail before the gesture is passed through to the cells underneath.

Comment: @Scriptable That's it ! Thanks ! But how can I keep my tapGesture on the view ? (I use that to hide the keyboard when the user is done editing)

Comment: There are common methods, I will post an example as an answer. you could also disable the gesture unless the keyboard is showing and then enable it on hide

Comment: You really should be dequeueing the cell from the tableview. Not init the cell like you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem will be conflicting gesture recogizers.

See [this Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/allowing_the_simultaneous_recognition_of_multiple_gestures) for some more details.

The easiest method to solve your issue would be to let the touch events passthrough to those below, you can do this by setting cancels touches in view to false on your gesture recogniser.

```
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Comment: Great, If this solves your issue please mark it as the answer to close the question. also please take note of Fogmeisters comment above, you should be reusing cells